# БД бота внутри секундомера

Tags: python, telebot

есть 2 файла, 1 - это бот, 2 - это секундомер

Проблема состоит в следующем, как в секундомере в периоде 4 часов, отнимать 1(из столбца food) у всех юзеров из БД бота, вот код секундомера

```
import asyncio
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("pdb.db")
sql = db.cursor()
db.commit()

async def start(sec, minute, hour):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        sec += 1
        if sec == 60:
             sec -= 60
             minute += 1
        if minute == 60:
             minute -= 60
             hour += 1
        if hour == 4:
             pass
```

я додумался до того, что-бы записывать id пользователя в список:

```py
id_user = []
for id in sql.execute("SELECT id FROM profile"):
    id = id[0]
    id_user.append(id)
```

Теперь есть почти-что самый главный вопрос, как пройтись по списку id_user по-очереди

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже нашел решение:

```
for test in id_user:
    print(f'food: {sql.execute(f"SELECT food FROM profile WHERE id = {test}").fetchone()[0]}')
```